# Height of div (where inside are images) doesn't change in automatic

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the `height` of div doesn't change automatically:

```
<div id="boximmagini">
    <div style="border-radius: 10px; background: #646464; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #505050; margin: 10px 2%; padding: 5px; text-align:center"><h3>Clicca e ingrandisci l'immagine</h3></div>
    <div><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/icpph2.jpg" class="imgoverlay" style="width: 28%" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/33jh1zp.jpg" class="imgoverlay" style="width: 28%" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/4hs6c6.jpg" class="imgoverlay"  style="width: 28%" /></div>
    <span style="clear:both">
</div>
```

This is CSS

```
.imgoverlay {
            float:left;
            border-radius: 10px; 
            margin: 2%; 
        }

#boximmagini {          
            background: #a0a0a0;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #505050;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

I don't know the `width` and `height` of each image, so I can't put a fixed measure of `height` for **`#boximmagini`**.
Besides I think that the height must change automatically...

Why doesn't work ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflow: auto` to the `#boximmagini`

```
#boximmagini {          
    background: #a0a0a0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #505050;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You have floated your images, this makes them go out of document flow and `#boximmagini` will not 'see' their height. You need to set that property so that it clears the floats and auto adjusts its height to its contents!

Comment: ok but why i must add overflow? if there are images in a div, the height doesn't change in automatic ?

Comment: @Shikkediel sorry I forgot to give an explanation, thanks for reminding me that.